# How to iterate through the list items and click on a desired list item using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to iterate through this list and select the element, can't figure it out.

Code trials:

```
butonlista = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='P17_OWNER01_EMAIL_AD']")))
butonlista.click()
search_result = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "(//ul[@role='listbox'])[1]")))
print(len(search_result))
for result in search_result:
    if "bacau@otpbank.ro" in result.text:
        result.click()
        break
```

But `print(len(search_result))` returns 1 element, what am I doing wrong?

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Comment: You're getting the parent element. There's only one parent element. Make an xpath for the child elements (maybe by adding li at the end). You want your Xpath to mark all the li elements below the current one

Answer (score 0):

Given the [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWzhG.png), *`bacau@otpbank.ro`* is the value of the `data-id` attribute of the first descendant `<li>` of it's parent `<ul role="listbox" ...>`

---

### Solution

To iterate through the all the `<li>` elements and click on the desired element you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
search_result = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='a-IconList' and @aria-labelledby='il1_info']//li")))
print(len(search_result))
for result in search_result:
    if "bacau@otpbank.ro" in result.get_attribute("data-id"):
        result.click()
        break
```